# Kubernetes access multiple cluster with KUBECONFIG variable on Windows

Tags: kubernetes

I am a newbie in kubernetes clustering therefore it might be a simple question. So I installed minikube on my local machine and it creates a config file into  $HOME/.kube/config. When I run *`kubectl config view`* command on Power Shell I can able to view the credentials. I already set a KUBECONFIG env variable and path is `$HOME/.kube/config.`

So the question is, in our company, we have an onpremise kubernetes cluster and I had a 2 different kubeconfig files per cluster. (one for stage one for production). What is the best way to define these kubeconfig files as an env variable to access these clusters?

What I tried, I put these files into `$HOME/.kube` directory and at the present I have three files such as *config , c1.kubeconfig,c2.kubeconfig* Then I updated my environment variable like 
`$HOME/.kube/config:$HOME/.kube/c1.kubeconfig:$HOME/.kube/c2.kubeconfig`. But this way I can not able to access c1 or c2 cluster.

Answer (score 3):

When you use KUBECONFIG environment variable you can only point it to one kubeconfig file and not to a series of kubeconfig files. You need to merge all the individual kubeconfig files into one kubeconfig file and store it as $HOME/.kube/config and then select a cluster using context flag of kubectl.

```
cp $HOME/.kube/config $HOME/.kube/config.backup.$(date +%Y-%m-%d.%H:%M:%S)
KUBECONFIG=$HOME/.kube/config:file2:file3 kubectl config view --merge --flatten > \
~/.kube/merged_kubeconfig && mv ~/.kube/merged_kubeconfig ~/.kube/config
kubectl get pods --context=cluster-1
kubectl get pods --context=cluster-2
```

[official docs here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/organize-cluster-access-kubeconfig/#merging-kubeconfig-files)

Comment: Hi @Arghya Sadhu, I could not able to run above command on windows. Here is the error that I received:KUBECONFIG=$HOME\.kube\config:$HOME\.kube\c1.kubeconfig\$HOME\.kube\c2.kubeconfig : The module 'KUBECONFIG=$HOME' could not be loaded. For more information, run 'Import-Module KUBECONFIG=$HOME'.

Answer (score 0):

Also explore kubectxwin power tools for better and faster context switch on windows

Git link for reference as below

https://github.com/thomasliddledba/kubectxwin

(This is Windows Version of the powerful tool kubectx  https://github.com/ahmetb/kubectx#installation)

Download Exe from this [link](https://github.com/thomasliddledba/kubectxwin/tree/master/bin)

Use in Power shell

```
PS C:\Users\DT> .\kubectxwin.exe ls
* kubernetes-admin@kubernetes

PS C:\Users\DT> .\kubectxwin.exe set kubernetes-admin@kubernetes
Switched to context "kubernetes-admin@kubernetes".
```

Example : Rename Context using the utility

```
PS C:\Users\DT> .\kubectxwin.exe rn kubernetes-admin@kubernetes kubeadmin
Context "kubernetes-admin@kubernetes" renamed to "kubeadmin".

PS C:\Users\DT> .\kubectxwin.exe ls
* kubeadmin
```

Comment: I could not able to see the Windows option.. It seems only refers to Linux or macOS

Comment: I was able to make it work with no issue .. Simply downloaded the exe file from repo and tested with no issues on windows power shell .. 

````PS C:\Users\DT> ./kubectxwin
kubernetes-admin@kubernetes
````  
**list context** ````PS C:\Users\DT> ./kubectxwin ls
* kubernetes-admin@kubernetes````

[exe link](https://github.com/thomasliddledba/kubectxwin/tree/master/bin)